# How to create graph with complex nodes using echarts and react?

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I need to create a graph with complex nodes like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xSw1.png)

The only vizualization library I am familiar with is echarts, but I can't find a way to do this with echarts. Closest call is rich text on label, but it doesn't seem possible to make labels as complex as these.
Is it possible to do this with echarts? Or maybe you can suggest another library? I had a quick search for vizualization libraries, but they all look similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library, it is called [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/docs/guides/custom-nodes/). And [here](https://dev.to/vaibhavkhulbe/make-interactive-node-based-graphs-with-react-flow-102d) is a guide on how to use it.